# TabBarController with SKScene - delay on presenting

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a tab bar controller that contains different ViewControllers.

One of them has a SKView and is creating a new SKScene in `viewDidLoad`

First time i navigate to the tab with the SKScene, it will display immediately, but every next time it will take about 2 seconds!

The strangest part is, the SKScene is totally empty! There is no nodes in it.
Every other view controller displays immediately.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267022/halt-when-presenting-viewcontroller-with-skscene?

Comment: Are you cache spriteKit resources for example at start of application, or you not?